# How to load a class two times using classloader in JVM?

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

I was asked in a Java interview. As we know, because of the parent delegation model, the Java class loader will load a class only once. So my answer is to use a custom class loader to load it. Is that right? How to answer this question?

Comment: Do you mean load a *class* twice?

Comment: @EJP,Yes,you are right

Comment: use two different classloaders

Comment: @JigarJoshi ... that don't delegate to each other.

Answer (score 4):

It depends. Classes whose qualified name starts with `java.` can only be loaded by the bootstrap loader and hence, not get loaded a second time at all. All other classes loaded by the bootstrap loader can only be loaded by a custom class loader implementation that doesn’t follow the parent delegation model, as the bootstrap loader is the parent of all loaders.

For all other classes, loaded by a `ClassLoader` instance, it is possible to construct a standard class loader, following the parent delegation model, but not having that loader as parent. But, of course, you can also use a custom loader for loading them, not following the delegation model. The choice might depend on how you want to handle other classes referenced by that class which have originally been loaded by the same loader. You may reload them as well, creating a complete copy of that environment or try to redirect their loading to the original loader, which will create problem if there are back-references.

The following code example demonstrates the approach:

```
public class ReloadMySelf {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        final Class<?> o = ReloadMySelf.class;
        URL loc = o.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
        ClassLoader parent = o.getClassLoader().getParent();
        try(URLClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{loc}, parent)) {
           Class<?> duplicate = cl.loadClass(o.getName());
           System.out.println("original: "+o+" ("+o.getClassLoader()+')');
           System.out.println("duplicate: "+duplicate+" ("+duplicate.getClassLoader()+')');
        }
    }
}
```